# Add TextArea to Datagrid in FLex 4

Tags: flex4, textarea

We are using Flex 4 in our Project. Here is one requirement. We have a AdvancedDataGrid control with some rows and columns. The there is one products column. Because the number of products is more, we want it to be displayed in a textArea.  We have a renderer for the products column. Once I click on the products column, This textarea should be visible just above the clicked column.

I have tried the following code inside the ProductsRenderer.mxml. The x and y here are arbitrary. When I click the column I am not able to see any text area.

```
    <fx:Declarations>   
        <parsley:Configure/>
</fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.height = 40;
            textArea.width  = 50;
            textArea.x = //get x for TextArea;
            textArea.y = //get y for TextArea;
            textArea.visible = true;
            textArea.setFocus();
            textArea.text = fProducts;
        }

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

<s:VGroup id="Box"
              paddingBottom="0"
              paddingTop="5"
              horizontalAlign="left" height="100%">
        <s:Label id="productsData" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" width="100%" click="clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

What should be done here to get the text area displayed on the grid? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the textArea to any parent container. Do something like:

```
protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.height = 40;
            textArea.width  = 50;
            textArea.x = //get x for TextArea;
            textArea.y = //get y for TextArea;
            textArea.visible = true;
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addChild(textArea); //this could be something else, showing an example here.
            textArea.setFocus();
            textArea.text = fProducts;
        }
```